# Every nonabelian group of order divisible by 6 contains a subgroup of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have a question I was hoping for help on:

> Prove or disprove every nonabelian group of order divisible by 6 contains a subgroup of order 6

I would guess that this statement is true based on a few examples I've done, but I have no idea why (or if it really is true). If I had a guess there might be some sort of isomorphism that I can relate non abelian groups of order 6 to. Would someone be able to help me? If you wouldn't mind, if you can help me, provide a simplistic explanation so that I may understand better. Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true.

You can verify that $A_4$ is a counterexample.

Comment: could {e,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)} be considered a subgroup of order 6 in $S_4$?

Comment: Yes, I am not saying thet $S_4$ is the counterexample, I am saying that a subgoup of $S_4$ is.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean the subgroup $S_4$ as a part of another, larger symmetric group? Say like $S_5$?

Comment: @BillyThorton: Exactly the opposite. Look at $A_4$ and show that this is the counterexample.

Comment: So, just for my understanding, the set I would examine in $A_4$ and the fact that it is a subgroup of $S_4$, then the counterexample would follow?

Comment: @BillyThorton $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$, even though its order $12$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: @BillyThorton: I edited the answer to make it more clear, sorry for any confusion. The "$S_4$-part" was supposed to be a hint (since I thought you want a hint only for some reason) - the point is, you are looking for a group which necessarily has elements of orders $2$ and $3$ (since $6$ divides the order of the group), but these two guys cannot commute (since otherwise they generate a $6$-element subgroup). So it is natural (at least it seems to me) to look for some suitable subgroup of symmetric group, where non-independent permutations tend to be non-commuting.

Comment: Since $S_3$ _is_ $6$-element group, one needs something bigger. In particular, $S_4$ is enough. One can choose there the element of order $2$ to be a double-transposition (say $(1 \;2)(3\;4)$) and element of order $3$ to be a $3$ cycle (e.g. $(1 \; 2 \; 3)$). Then one can verify that this actually works.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now. $A_4$ has 12 elements - which is divisible by 6, however, there is no subgroup of order 6 in $A_4$. Correct?

Comment: @BillyThorton: Yes.